# PHPUnit & CakePHP 3 - Constant DS already defined in paths.php

Tags: unit-testing, phpunit, cakephp-3.0

When I run phpunit for my cake 3 project I get the following notice:

`PHP Notice:  Constant DS already defined in /path/to/project/config/paths.php on line 18`

But I don´t find where it tries to redefine the constant? I mean the defining in paths.php is correct!

Comment: https://github.com/cakephp/app/commit/d314132403deb4bd7929fc08ea846ff9f77897e2

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Update your path.php file so that it looks like this one:

https://github.com/cakephp/app/blob/master/config/paths.php#L18